# How can I use inner node of templates in knockout?

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I want to know if it's possible to use knockout templates the way described further.

Suppose the case is to make an abstract gallery.
Let the template be defined the following way:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'galleryTemplate', data: data}">
  <img data-bind="attr:{src:thmbn}" />
</div>
```

Now, gallery template in this case might me defined the following way:

```
<div id="galleryTemplate">
  <div data-bind="foreach: {data: items}">
     /* inner node of template from above */
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks good, but I don't have any ideas how to implement it in knockout.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you should define a `template` with unique id. You can do this with `div` but I prefer to use `script` tag for this:

```
<script id="galleryTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <img  data-bind="attr:{src:thmbn}" style="width:200px" />
    </div>
</script>
```

And then you it where you want:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'galleryTemplate', data: data}">
</div>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pm7Y9/1/

Comment: No, you don't understand me right. You just described a standart way to use a template in knockout. But using this approach you won't be able to use abstract html markup for items in your gallery template. My approach allows to set this markup in the body of a gallery template, therefore I can use any way of item presentation in my gallery.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, but not trivial, to write a custom binding that would try to do what you are after.

However, I think that an easier approach would be to pass in the name of a template to the "galleryTemplate" and then use it to render the children.

Something like:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'galleryTemplate', data: { templateName: 'itemTmplOne', data: data } }"></div>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'galleryTemplate', data: { templateName: 'itemTmplTwo', data: data } }"></div>

<script id="galleryTemplate" type="text/html">
  <div data-bind="template: { name: templateName, foreach: data }"></div>
</script>​

<script id="itemTmplOne" type="text/html">
    <div>one</div>
</script>

<script id="itemTmplTwo" type="text/html">
    <div>two</div>
</script>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jdJPc/